# Get nested JSON data with Retrofit

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-activity, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit like this:

```
final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(URL)
        .build();

final ApiEndpointInterface apiService = restAdapter.create(ApiEndpointInterface.class);

apiService.getData(userId, new Callback<UserData>() {

    @Override
    public void success(UserData userData, Response response) {

        // get data

    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        retrofitError.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

The JSON it requests is in this form:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "data":[
        {
            "id":"11",
            "name":"John"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I access the `name` of the user within the `success` callback of Retrofit?

Here are my models. **UserData**:

```
public class UserData {

    @Expose
    private Boolean success;
    @Expose
    private List<User> data = new ArrayList<User>();

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The success
     */
    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param success
     * The success
     */
    public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The data
     */
    public List<User> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param data
     * The data
     */
    public void setData(List<User> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

**User**:

```
public class User {

    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("name")

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * The id
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

   /**
     *
     * @return
     * The message
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param message
     * The message
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: It Should be someting like this List<User> user=userData.getData(). And on then you can iterate it, and fecth the user name.

Comment: `getData()` is a `List`. Should it not be?

Comment: Check the edit, Sorry I didn't notice the List

Comment: @AkshayMukadam I'm wondering though, since the JSON will always only return one result within `data`, should I keep it as a `List` or change it to just `User`?

Comment: Use this site http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org. Post your json over there. Select Source Type as JSON, and select gson as your annotation style. It will give u ready parsers, this will help to solve your confusion.

Comment: In anyways the data is arraylist it cannot be an object

Comment: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Answer (score 0):

Use the GsonConveter to deserialize the nested class

```
       RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(URL). setConverter(new GsonConverter(new GsonBuilder()
               .registerTypeAdapter(UserData.class, new ExplorerDeserializerJson())
               .create()))
                .build();


public class ExplorerDeserializerJson implements sonDeserializer<UserData> {             


   @Override     
   public  UserData deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
        throws JsonParseException {
    UserData userdata= new UserData();

       JsonArray jsonArray = je.getAsJsonArray();
       Log.d(TAG,"Trying");
       Gson gson = new Gson();

    for(JsonElement element : jsonArray){
        JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();

       User   userid= gson.fromJson(jsonObject.get("id"),      User.class);
        userdata.addgallery(userid);

    }
    return userdata;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you have @SerializedName below variable? Also name of "id" matches the json, so you do not need @SerializedName annotation